# MsSQL - Return results within a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

I need to return database results based on a date range, im using Classic ASP and MsSQL

My script gives me dates formatted as follows:

```
6/18/2014
```

The dates are saved in the database in the following format

```
12/24/2014 7:03:00 AM
```

What im wanting to do is something as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE paid >= 6/18/2014 AND =< 6/28/2014
```

When i run that, im getting weird results as the dates arent formatted the same.

Can someone help me out.

Cheers,

Comment: What data type is the column where you store the dates?

Comment: it should be `DATE` type

Comment: @rock321987 Order of the operators has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put those two dates between single quotes like..

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE paid BETWEEN '6/18/2014' and '6/28/2014'`

**EDIT:**

you can use `DATE_FORMAT(date,format)` function to display date/time data in different formats.

here's some reference 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Comment: Ahhhh now im getting somewhere .... Its returning results, i have to check to make sure they are correct.

Comment: Okay if find this helpful and this answer your question you can accept my answer or vote up :) ... I'm glad to help you.. happy coding.. :D

Comment: So the question is tagged [tag:sql-server] and you provide references to [tag:mysql] code and the OP still accepts it?

Answer (score 0):

if its not typo

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE paid BETWEEN '6/18/2014' AND '6/28/2014'

**EDIT**:-my database is storing it in the format yyyy-mm-dd

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE DATE >=  '2014-05-18'
AND DATE <=  '2014-06-28'
```

and its working correctly

[here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_2209321_2/Working-with-SQL-Server-DateTime-Variables-Part-Three---Searching-for-Particular-Date-Values-and-Ranges.htm) is a reference

change the format according to your own database it will work

Comment: Im still not getting any results ... I think its because the dates are incorrectly formatted, is there a way to format them in the SQL

Comment: it is using `BETWEEN`

Comment: Ok, its not erroring, but its not returning any results either ... Is it because the date that im inputting is formatted different to the date format in the database?

Comment: The OP is using SQL Server it even says that in the tags, if you don't want to provide T-SQL syntax...don't bothering answering. That syntax will work as `BETWEEN` is valid but the date values need to be passed as `varchar` as `#` isn't valid.